# Applying Gauss' Theorem to a sphere not centered at the origin

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> *Determine $$\iint_S \textbf{A} \cdot d\textbf{S}$$
>   where $$\textbf{A}(x,y,z) = (xz^2,x^2y,xyz)$$ and S is the sphere $(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2+(z+3)^2=4$*.

**Attempted solution**

Let's use Gauss' theorem. We obtain $\nabla \cdot \textbf{A} = x^2+z^2+xy$. A parametrization of the sphere is given by:
$$\Phi(r,\theta,\phi)=\cases{x=r\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)-1\\y=r\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)-2\\z=r\cos(\phi)+3}\\$$
with $dV = r^2\sin(\phi)dr\,d\theta \,d\phi$. Furthermore we get: $$\textbf{A}(\Phi)=(r\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)-1)^2+(r\cos(\phi)+3)^2+[r\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)-1][(r\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)-2]$$
Gauss theorem then gives:
$$\begin{multline*}\iint_S \textbf{A} \cdot d\textbf{S} =\iiint_V \Big( r^2\sin(\phi)(r\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)-1)^2+r^2\sin(\phi)(r\cos(\phi)+3)^2 \\+r^2\sin(\phi)[r\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)-1][(r\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)-2]\Big) \,dr\,d\theta\, d\phi\end{multline*}$$

**Question**

Is there a simpler way, because I'm not too keen on working with that beast?

Comment: Maybe, you could use the Stokes formula, hit: $A\cdot dS=xz^2dy\wedge dz+x^2ydz\wedge dx+xyzdx\wedge dy$

Comment: @DLIN What would the boundary be? And what are those symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a translational change of coordinates, namely,
$$x = u + 1, \quad y = v + 2, \quad z = w - 3$$
so that the sphere $V$ is centered at the origin in the new coordinates. Then,
$${\bf A}(u, v, w) = ((u + 1)(w - 3)^2, (u + 1)^2 (v + 2), (u + 1) (v + 2) (w - 3))$$
and so
$$
\begin{align*}
(\nabla \cdot {\bf A})(u, v, w)
&= (w - 3)^2 + (u + 1)^2 + (u + 1)(v + 2) \\
&= u^2 + uv + w^2 + 4 u + v - 6 w + 12 .
\end{align*}
$$
If we integrate this expression over the sphere $V$, then by symmetry the $uv$, $u$, $v$, and $w$ terms do not contribute, and Gauss' Theorem gives
$$\iint_S \nabla \cdot {\bf A} \,d{\bf S} = \iiint_V (u^2 + w^2 + 12) \,du\,dv\,dw.$$
Again by symmetry, the integrals of $u^2$ and $w^2$ over $V$ coincide, and our integral is equal to
$$2 \iiint_V u^2 \,du\,dv\,dw + 12 \iiint_V \,du\,dv\,dw .$$
The first integral can be evaluated quickly using spherical coordinates, and, of course, the integral in the second term is just the volume of $V$.

**Edit** As user8268 points out in the comments, we can simplify the computation of the first integral in the last display equation by again appealing to symmetry: With the spherical coordinate change $r^2 = u^2 + v^2 + w^2$ in mind, we can rewrite the integral as $$\iiint_V u^2 \,du\,dv\,dw = \frac{1}{3} \iiint_V (u^2 + v^2 + w^2) \,du\,dv\,dw .$$

Comment: a little remark - in the first integral you can replace $u^2$ with $(u^2+v^2+w^2)/3$, which gives a simpler integral $2/3\times 4\pi\times\int_0^1 r^4\,dr$

Comment: @user8268 That's very neat! You probably meant to $\int_{0}^{2}r^4dr$ though :)

Comment: This trick did it, @Travis. I see how the $u,v,w$ terms cancel in the end. How could you be sure the $uv$ term wouldn't contribute? Because the product consists of variables with odd powers?

Comment: Yes, that's right. In fact, an integral $\iiint_V u^a v^b w^c \,dV$ of a monomial over a sphere $V$ is zero if /any/ of the exponents $a, b, c$ is odd: By relabeling, suppose it's $a$; then, the integrand is odd w.r.t. $u$ and so the integral is zero.